# Gulp not copying files to destination folder but recreating all source folder structure in destination

Tags: symfony, gulp

I have created a Gulp task and it executes successfully:

```
gulp.task('images', function () {
    gulp.src('src/**/Resources/public/images/*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('web/images/'))
        .pipe(reload({stream:true}));
});
```

I have images in `src/Members/Bundle/ManagementBundle/Resources/public/images`, and when the task is run, I have files copied in `web/images/Members/Bundle/ManagementBundle/Resources/public/images`.

I don't understand why? I need the files to be copied in `web/images/` only. Help is much apprecited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is about adding the `base` parameter to `gulp.src`:

```
gulp.task('images', function () {
    gulp.src('src/**/Resources/public/images/*', {
            base: 'src/Members/Bundle/ManagementBundle/Resources/public/images/'
        })
        .pipe(gulp.dest('web/images/'))
        .pipe(reload({stream:true}));
});
```

thank you all for your time.